# Initialize array of objects from text files

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, bufferedreader

I have a program where I need to store users information, and add users. To make it persistent, the program reads all the users data and initializes an array of users upon launch, then saves the information before it closes. Here's my user class:

```
class User {
    String name;
    int val = -1;
    int oldVal = -1;

    public User(String n){
        try{
             BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/" + n));
             name = dataReader.readLine();
             val = Integer.parseInt(dataReader.readLine());
             oldVal = Integer.parseInt(dataReader.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

This class reads from files in /users, following the format name.txt

```
 John
 90
 100
```

My core class looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

class Core{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int numUsers = -1;
        BufferedReader nameReader = null;
        User[] users = null;

        try {
            nameReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Users/users.txt"));
            numUsers = Integer.parseInt(nameReader.readLine());
            users = new User[numUsers];

            for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++){
                users[i] = new User(nameReader.readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong. Aborting!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++){
            System.out.println("User " + users[i].getName() + "\n Val:" + users[i].getVal() + "\n oldVal: " + users[i].getOldVal());
        }
    }
}
```

But running core returns:

```
User null
val: -1
oldVal: -1
```

for every user. 
What is the problem? Is the system I've made viable, or do I need to change the foundation of my program entirely?

(EDIT to change tags)

Comment: I guess an exception occurs in your constructor, but due to this line `catch (Exception e){}`, you'll ignore that. Write `e.printStackTrace()` into that catch block to see the exception. And if you get one, please edit your question and post the stacktrace here.

Comment: @tom I get a compile time error: "Cannot find symbolm, symbol: printStacktrace() location: variable e of type exception" Odd.EDIT: capitalization error, oops.

Comment: because I had a typo in it. The correct spelling is `printStackTrace()` (uppercase `T`). I edited the first comment.

Comment: @tom I was specifying the files as a path. Adding '+ ".txt"' should fix it, checking now. EDIT: I also needed to get rid of the slash before "Users".

Comment: Don't forget to read `chiastic-security`s answer. His remark is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core is looking for a file in the relative path `Users/`. Your other class is looking in the absolute path `/Users/`.

Your textual description says you want `/users/` (lower case). On some systems, this will be different again.

I suspect this is causing the problem, or at least part of it.

Looks like what you really want is a relative path, and a `.txt` on the end:

```
BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Users/" + n + ".txt"));
```

Comment: The additional slash before should not be there, as the path is supposed to be relative. The .txt extension is also missing. I'm unable to mark my own answer, so if you could edit yours to include this I'd be grateful! (and thanks for answering!)

Answer (score 0):

```
 BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/" + n));
```

Should be

```
 BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Users/" + n + ".txt"));
```

Notice the removal of the extra forward slash and the addition of the .txt extension.